# Factory Bot associations with namespaced model glitching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, namespaces, factory-bot

When trying to build namespaced associations, Factorybot does not register the namespace, but rather uses its own despite defining it just like documentation (and every thread on SO says).

Model `Admin::TicketCategory`

`class Admin::TicketCategory < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tickets
end`

And its factory:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :ticket_category, class: Admin::TicketCategory do |f|
    f.text { Faker::Commerce.product_name }
  end
end
```

The `Ticket` model:

```
class Ticket < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :service_rep, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :user_id
  belongs_to :ticket_category
  belongs_to :ticket_status
  belongs_to :ticket_urgency
  has_many :ticket_comments
end
```

And its factory:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :ticket do |f|
    f.user
    f.ticket_category
    f.subject { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
    f.body { Faker::Lorem.paragraph }
    f.ticket_urgency { admin_ticket_urgency }
    f.ticket_status { admin_ticket_status }
    f.service_rep { user }
  end
end
```

When I try to validate the `Ticket` model, this error comes up:

```
  1) Ticket has a valid factory
 Failure/Error: expect(FactoryBot.create(:ticket)).to be_valid

 NameError:
   uninitialized constant Ticket::TicketCategory
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how rails works when it comes to namespaced models:
It will try to find out the associated model in current namespace.

Let's start with the associations that you defined:

In `Admin::TicketCategory` it should have `has_many: tickets, class_name: "Ticket"` (assuming you have `ticket_category_id` in `Ticket` model). And in your `Ticket` model you should have `belongs_to: ticket_category, class_name: "Admin::TicketCategory`.

This should be sufficient to make it work